# What does the 过 mean in 我有点过厌他?

Tags: vocabulary

I came across this sentence and the translation is roughly `"I'm a little tired of him."` but I'm curious as to what purpose 过 serves here?

Am I right to think that `我有点过厌他。` also means `"I'm a little tired of him."`?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? It doesn't look like proper Chinese.

Comment: I found it in a textbook that my school made. I go to a university in Korea so I wouldn't be surprised if this wasn't proper Chinese.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure it is a typo

我有点过厌他 should be  我有点讨厌他 (I am a little bit disgusted with him/ I am kind of hating him)

讨厌 = disgusted with; hate

过厌 makes no sense

*In traditional Chinese characters, you wouldn't confusing 過(过) with 討(讨) so easily*

Comment: I wonder if the text is written by hand. *The typo* won't happen if you type it on devices, unless you use the handwriting feature.

Answer (score 0):

我有点过厌他 literally，"a little too tired of him"  see online dictionaries, esp. bkrs: 过 IV

(1) 过分; ; 过于; 太甚 [excessive]
以其境过清, 不可久居, 乃记之而去。 --唐·柳宗元《至小丘西小石潭记》
古者天下之人爱戴其君, 比之如父母; 拟之如天, 诚不过也。 --清·黄宗羲《原君》
(2) 又如: 过爱(过分的爱); 过余(过分); 过头话(过分的大话)

maybe 讨厌 would make better sense, and be much more common

Comment: No one say 过厌  instead of 太过讨厌 or  过分讨厌.

Comment: absolutely, who would argue otherwise, if 过厌 existed
, there would be examples at iciba, users also note that 厌 seems to be a bound morpheme only occurring in fixed combinations 无厌,看厌了,厌恶,厌弃 (过厌 not among them)

Answer (score 0):

the right meaning should be 我有点受不了他 ,  tired of  somebody means "对 somebody 受不了/厌烦/讨厌/闹心"